# Подскажите откуда при мобильной адаптации берется прокрутка внизу?

Tags: html, css

```css
.main
{  
 width: 1500px;
 margin: 0 auto 0;
}

.suprecipes
{ 
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto 0;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
 -webkit-box-direction: normal;
     -ms-flex-direction: row;
         flex-direction: row;

}
.recipes
{ 
 margin-top: 2.6%;
 width: 33.3%;
 height: 111px;
 background: #eabc74;
 line-height: 111px;
}
.recipes-second-row
{ 
 margin-top: 17px;
 height: 80px;
 line-height: 0px;
}
.recipes-center-color
{
 background: #f1962e;
}

.recipes-text
{ 
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 62%;
 height: 37px;
 line-height: 37px;
 background: #ee7b00;
}

.recipes-text-caption
{ 
 font:  18px/30px 'Mouse Memoirs',sans-serif;
 padding-left: 0.7em; 
 color: #131313;
}
.recipes-text-row-two
{
 font:  12px/12px 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
 line-height: 12px;
 margin-left: 2.8em;
 display: block;
}

.recipes-text-caption-row-two
{ 
 font:  18px/30px 'Mouse Memoirs',sans-serif;
 padding-left: 0.7em;
 margin-top:0.8em;
 margin-left: 1.3em;
 margin-bottom: 0.1em;  
 color: #131313;
 width: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) 
{
  
  
  .main
 {
  width: 100%;
 }
  .suprecipes
 { 
  width:100%;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
          
 }
  
  .recipes
 {
  width:100%;
  margin-left: 0px;
 }
 .recipes-second-row
 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 0px;
 }
  
  .recipes-text-row-two
 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
  
  
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="main">
    <section class="suprecipes">
  <div class="recipes recipes-second-row">
   <p class="recipes-text-caption-row-two">Special Diets</p>
   <span class="recipes-text-row-two">Low-salt, egg-free, dairy-free and gluten-free are just some of the options.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="recipes recipes-second-row recipes-center-color">
   <p class="recipes-text-caption-row-two">Vegetarian</p>
   <span class="recipes-text-row-two">Tempting meat-free meals and other vegetarian fare.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="recipes recipes-second-row">
   <p class="recipes-text-caption-row-two">Need Inspiration?</p>
   <span class="recipes-text-row-two">Use our refined recipe search to help you find the dish that suits you</span>
  </div>
 </section>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Подскажите откуда при мобильной адаптации берется прокрутка внизу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скорее всего не обнулены стили, которые используются по умолчанию. Также нет meta тега для viewport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас тег с классом "recipes-text-caption-row-two" рвет верстку, уберите ширину 100%

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте!

Попробуйте добавить в head html-документа мета-тег

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```